# overlay 2 images with transparency in R

Tags: r, image, overlay

I have 2 images I import in R:

```
image_A <- load.image('C:/Image test/testA.jpg')
image_B <- load.image('C:/Image test/testB.jpg')
```

I would like to superpose/overlay the image B to A and applying a transparency to image B.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Give a read to magick package documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html). It's used to perform image processing in general. It may help you to resolve with your issue.

Comment: If they're jpegs, they don't have a transparent background (like you can have with pngs), so it's going to be a little work. What's the context? Are these plots?

Comment: Well, maybe reading the pixels color and then using this idea presented here: https://menugget.blogspot.com/2012/04/adding-transparent-image-layer-to-plot.html#more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option, using `rasterImage` from base R.

First lets get two images. For the first we read in the R logo jpeg.  Then add another array layer to hold the alpha channel (jpegs do not have transparency)

```
img.logo = jpeg::readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))
img.logo = abind::abind(img.logo, img.logo[,,1]) # add an alpha channel
```

For the second image, lets make it an array the same dimensions as img.1, but fill it with random colors

```
img.random = img.logo
img.random[] = runif(prod(dim(img.random))) # this image is random colors
```

Now lets set the base image to fully opaque, and the R logo to semi-transparent

```
img.logo[,,4] = 0.5  # set alpha to semi-transparent
img.random[,,4] = 1  # set alpha to 1 (opaque)
```

Now we have our example images, we can superimpose them using `rasterImage`.

```
png('test.png', width = 2, height = 2, units = 'in', res = 150)
  par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
  plot.new()
  rasterImage(img.random, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  rasterImage(img.logo,   0, 0, 1, 1)
dev.off()
```

[image]