# How to overlay the values of the cells in a heatmap made with the function image() in R?

Tags: r

I'm producing a heat map with the function image():

```
testmatrix <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
image(1:10,1:10,testmatrix)
```

[image]

I need each cell to display the value inside them, but so far haven't found a way to do it. This functionality doesn't seem to be integrated in the function itself. Is there a way to do this?

(I know heatmap() could do this more straightforwardly, but I am forced to use image() to later integrate the code into another function.)

Comment: If you *have to* refrain from dedicated libraries: there's an option to overlay images in base R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822337/overlay-2-images-with-transparency-in-r . So you might render a second, equal-sized image from a plot containing labels only and overlay them. The result will probably be ugly though.

Answer (score 2):

Using `text`:

```r
testmatrix <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
image(1:10, 1:10, testmatrix)

# Create a grid with x, y, and values (z)
grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(nrow(testmatrix)), y = seq(ncol(testmatrix))) 
out <- transform(grid, z = testmatrix[as.matrix(grid)])
txt <- out[order(out$x), ]

text(txt$x, txt$y, round(txt$z, 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Reshape the matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15885111/680068), then use *text*:

```
#reproducible data
set.seed(1); testmatrix <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)

# convert matrix into 3 column dataframe, x, y, and label
txt <- as.data.frame(as.table(testmatrix))

# then plot text after image function
image(1:10,1:10,testmatrix)
with(txt, text(Var1, Var2, round(Freq, 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround!+

Comment: @Maël thanks, had to google though, keep forgetting the `as.table` function.

Comment: I did not really know it either actually, looking it now and I'm quite intrigued by the fact that it creates LETTERS row and col names.

Comment: @Maël They are `factor(LETTERS)`, so they are integers with names, as a result `text` is happy with the input for x and y.

Comment: Alright! this is nice

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row(testmatrix)` and `col(testmatrix)` as `x` and `y` arguments when calling `text`

```r
testmatrix <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
image(1:10,1:10,testmatrix)

text(x = row(testmatrix),
     y = col(testmatrix),
     label = sprintf("%.2f", testmatrix))
```

[image]